# Animation on an electron app stops after some time of losing focus

Tags: javascript, animation, electron, rendering

I'm making some simple widget like app for twitch streams using electron.
basically what i need is to display some data and play some animations on loop while running on the background.

i tried using anime js and velocity js, but seems like both have a problem where they stop playing some time after losing focus (maybe even stops rendering at all)

is there any way to prevent that from happening?

Comment: I believe that's a feature, not a bug. I observed similar behaviour with Chromium (Electron's based on that) running on a dedicated GPU on Linux. Can you confirm that your code/animation has the same "issue" when run in a browser-only environment and not Electron (if possible)?

Comment: Can't since the app relies a lot on the node integration feature, but given it's a chromium thing if electron doesn't offers a solution to disable said feature i might be on a dead end here and will have to start from scratch in another language